# vidalia says I'm connected to tor, but https://check.torproject.org/ says I am not

Tags: tor

I installed Vidalia and it says I am connected to the Tor network. But https://check.torproject.org/ says I am not using Tor. How can I troubleshoot the discrepancy?

Answer (score 2):

Both are correct. Vidalia *did* start Tor, which *did* connect to the Tor network and is now waiting for programs to use it. But Tor is only a proxy and Vidalia is only a controller; it *does not* automagically set your entire OS to use Tor automatically – you have to configure each program manually, and in some cases use additional tools.

When started, Tor can be used as a regular proxy server; it is listening on connections at `127.0.0.1` (localhost) on port `9050`, using the SOCKS protocol. For example, in Firefox the configuration would look like this:

[image: Firefox screenshot]

For programs that do not support SOCKS proxies but do support HTTP, the Vidalia bundle also includes a HTTP proxy server called Polipo, which listens on port `8123` and sends everything through Tor. You might need to start Polipo manually.

For programs that do not allow using a proxy at all, you'll need tools like [FreeCap](http://www.freecap.ru/eng/) or [WideCap](http://widecap.ru/en/help/) or `torsocks` that hook into the system.

All of this is described in [Step Two: Configure your applications to use Tor](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-doc-windows.html.en#using) of the Tor install instructions, as well as the [Torify HOWTO](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/doc/TorifyHOWTO) linked from the same page.